# Keep DC part of distinguished name

Tags: powershell, distinguishedname

I have for input distinguished names like the following:

```
CN=A00.user,OU=MyOU,OU=A00,OU=MyOU3,DC=my,DC=domain
CN=A01.user1,OU=MyOU1,OU-MyOU2,OU=A00,OU=MyOU3,DC=my,DC=first,DC=domain
```

I need to print only the DC part, to get an output like:

```
my.domain
my.first.domain
```

Looks like split or replace should work, but I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply remove everything up to and including the first `,DC=` and then replace the remaining `,DC=` with dots.

```
$dn = 'CN=A00.user,OU=MyOU,OU=A00,OU=MyOU3,DC=my,DC=domain',
      'CN=A01.user1,OU=MyOU1,OU-MyOU2,OU=A00,OU=MyOU3,DC=my,DC=first,DC=domain'

$dn -replace '^.*?,dc=' -replace ',dc=', '.'
```

Comment: Hopefully no distinguishedName components contain the string `,DC=` (you never know, I've seen some strange object names...).

Comment: Whoever puts a string `,DC=` in their name components deserves whatever pain follows.

Comment: Perhaps, but it is still legal to have it in a name component, and in IMO a script should be robust enough to work with all legal names. This is why I always recommend using the `Pathname` object.

Comment: According to [Richard L. Mueller](http://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm) a `=` would have to be escaped, meaning that the sequence `,DC=` can only occur in a root DN. ([more complete version](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5312.active-directory-characters-to-escape.aspx))

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Get-ADPathname.ps1](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/powershell-active-directory-paths) with the `-Split` parameter, `Select-String` with a regular expression, and the `-join` operator:

```
(
  Get-ADPathname 'CN=A01.user1,OU=MyOU1,OU-MyOU2,OU=A00,OU=MyOU3,DC=my,DC=first,DC=domain' -Split | Select-String '^DC=(.+)' | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
  }
) -join '.'
```

Output:

```
my.first.domain
```

Comment: Looks like a great script Bill, If I need to work more with the distinguished names, I will definitely take a look. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty way to get it done.

```
("CN=A00.user,OU=MyOU,OU=A00,OU=MyOU3,DC=my,DC=domain " -split "," | 
Where-Object { $_.StartsWith("DC=") } | 
ForEach-Object { $_.Replace("DC=","")}) -join "."
```

Produces 
my.domain

Comment: That's true. I was not aware that DNs could have commas in the name, other than dividing CN, OU, and DN.

Comment: On my network at work, commas are a required part of the naming standard.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Could you paste an example of what it might look like for my benefit?

Comment: I always recommend using the `Pathname` object to parse AD paths, which is what the Get-ADPathname.ps1 script does (see my answer).

Comment: Interesting. I used the DN in your example and my script split it just fine. Perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: Your example will work as long as a distinguishedName component does not contain a `,` character.